# Google TV audio tag support

Tags: html5-audio, google-tv

What formats Google TV browser(Google Chrome) html5 "audio" tag supports? I have an issue with playback of streaming links. I have already seen this link(http://code.google.com/p/googletv-issues/issues/detail?id=5) but is there official approving and more deeply problem explanation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checked Chrome/11.0.696.77 on my Google TV using html5test.com and here is the result for audio/video:

Video: MPEG-4 and H.264 supported but not Ogg Theora and WebM
 Audio: ACC and MP3 supported but not PCM, Ogg Vorbis, WebM

Interestingly my Mac Chrome 18.0.1025.165 supports H.264, Ogg Theora and WebM but not MPEG-4 for video and all five for audio.

Comment: Actually it supports MP3 files, but not MP3 stream. :(

Answer (score 1):

You could try out http://html5test.com/  to check for all HTML5 supported features in GoogleTV browser including supported audio formats.

This is the list of supported audio formats for Google Tv Browser:
[image]

If you find any issues, please report it at:
http://code.google.com/p/googletv-issues/